# Sitecore Glass.Mapper VersionCountDisabler is disposed of too early

Tags: glass-mapper

Recently I've been exploring Glass Mapper for Sitecore and stumbled upon a very strange issue.

**PROBLEM**

Imagine  you have an item of `MyModel` and it contains a few Droplink fields that point to other items. The `MyModel` item exists only in one language (so are the linked items), i.e. it is a helper item that is used in dropdowns and has only shared fields, so it makes no sense to keep a version of it in every language.

Now, the Glass Mapper team recommends using `VersionCountDisabler` like this:

```
using(new VersionCountDisabler()){

    var model =  sitecoreService.GetItem<MyModel>("/sitecore/content/home");

}
```

But in my project I've noticed that if I don't access any property of `model` while inside the using statement and the code reaches the closing curly bracket (and the instance of the `VersionCountDisabler` get disposed of) then all the properties in my model get set back to null.
If I, however, access *any* property while *inside* the using statement, I will be able to access my model properties even when the `VersionCountDisabler` is disposed of.

Apparently the proxy object is killed when the `VersionCountDisabler` is being disposed of.

**DESIRED BEHAVIOR**

In my world Glass Mapper should keep the field values regardless of me accessing them inside the `VersionCountDisabler`

Answer (score 4):

I believe linked items by default are loaded lazily, which is probably what is causing this.

If you first access the property outside the `VersionCountDisabler` then the items are loaded without it.

An alternative solution to your own answer could be to try and use `SitecoreFieldSettings.DontLoadLazily` on the properties in question. The items should then all be loaded and mapped inside the `VersionCountDisabler`.

```
// Attribute configuration
[SitecoreField(Setting = SitecoreFieldSettings.DontLoadLazily)]
public IList<MyLinkedItem> LinkedItems { get; set; }

// Fluent configuration
Map(x => x.Field(y => y.LinkedItems ).Setting(SitecoreFieldSettings.DontLoadLazily));
```

Comment: Yes, disabling Lazy Loading on droplink fields seems to have done the trick too, though I wish Glass Mapper had a built-in functionality to Lazy load fields with version count disabled. I am going to test both approaches in the project I am currently working to see which one works better.

Comment: Yea, I've been looking for similar functionality before but haven't gotten around to creating a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure if it's a bug in Glass Mapper or not (I think it's not), but there seems to be an article on the Internet that kind of addresses the problem: https://ctor.io/shared-field-references-in-glass-mapper/

However, the article is rather outdated (it has been written for Glass.Mapper V3) and it covers only the attribute part of the problem without even touching the FluentAPI which I prefer to attributes.

So I decided to extend the solution proposed there and add support for FluentAPI mappings.

I took the `SitecoreSharedFieldTypeMapper` and `SitecoreSharedFieldConfiguration` almost as they are (The `SitecoreSharedFieldConfiguration' does not have the`Copy()` override anymore, so I removed it) and added two more classes:

```
public class SitecoreSharedField<T> : AbstractPropertyBuilder<T, SitecoreSharedFieldConfiguration>
{
    public SitecoreSharedField(Expression<Func<T, object>> ex) : base(ex)
    {
        this.Configuration.FieldName = this.Configuration.PropertyInfo.Name;
    }

    public SitecoreSharedField<T> IsCodeFirst()
    {
        this.Configuration.CodeFirst = true;
        return this;
    }

    public SitecoreSharedField<T> FieldId(string id)
    {
        return this.FieldId(new ID(id));
    }

    public SitecoreSharedField<T> FieldId(Guid id)
    {
        return this.FieldId(new ID(id));
    }

    public SitecoreSharedField<T> FieldId(ID id)
    {
        this.Configuration.FieldId = id;
        return this;
    }

    public SitecoreSharedField<T> FieldName(string name)
    {
        this.Configuration.FieldName = name;
        return this;
    }

    public SitecoreSharedField<T> FieldSource(string fieldSource)
    {
        this.Configuration.FieldSource = fieldSource;
        return this;
    }

    public SitecoreSharedField<T> FieldTitle(string fieldTitle)
    {
        this.Configuration.FieldTitle = fieldTitle;
        return this;
    }

    public SitecoreSharedField<T> FieldType(SitecoreFieldType fieldType)
    {
        this.Configuration.FieldType = fieldType;
        return this;
    }

    public SitecoreSharedField<T> IsShared()
    {
        this.Configuration.IsShared = true;
        return this;
    }

    public SitecoreSharedField<T> IsUnversioned()
    {
        this.Configuration.IsUnversioned = true;
        return this;
    }

    public SitecoreSharedField<T> CustomFieldType(string fieldType)
    {
        this.Configuration.CustomFieldType = fieldType;
        return this;
    }

    public SitecoreSharedField<T> Setting(SitecoreFieldSettings setting)
    {
        this.Configuration.Setting = setting;
        return this;
    }

    public SitecoreSharedField<T> SectionName(string sectionName)
    {
        this.Configuration.SectionName = sectionName;
        return this;
    }

    public SitecoreSharedField<T> ReadOnly()
    {
        this.Configuration.ReadOnly = true;
        return this;
    }

    public SitecoreSharedField<T> FieldSortOrder(int order)
    {
        this.Configuration.FieldSortOrder = order;
        return this;
    }

    public SitecoreSharedField<T> SectionSortOrder(int order)
    {
        this.Configuration.SectionSortOrder = order;
        return this;
    }

    public SitecoreSharedField<T> ValidationErrorText(string text)
    {
        this.Configuration.ValidationErrorText = text;
        return this;
    }

    public SitecoreSharedField<T> ValidationRegularExpression(string regex)
    {
        this.Configuration.ValidationRegularExpression = regex;
        return this;
    }

    public SitecoreSharedField<T> IsRequired()
    {
        this.Configuration.IsRequired = true;
        return this;
    }
}
```

and

```
public static class SitecoreTypeExtensions
{
    public static SitecoreSharedField<T> SharedField<T>(this SitecoreType<T> type, Expression<Func<T, object>> ex)
    {
        SitecoreSharedField<T> sitecoreField = new SitecoreSharedField<T>(ex);
        type.Config.AddProperty((AbstractPropertyConfiguration)sitecoreField.Configuration);
        return sitecoreField;
    }
}
```

The first one simply adds a proper instance `SitecoreSharedFieldConfiguration` class to the field configuration and the second one is an extension method for `SitecoreType` that adds the new field to the FluentApi.

Now, whenever I have an item in Sitecore which I want glass mapper to take any available language version of and get the values from it, I use the following FluentApi configuration:

```
var themeConfiguration = loader.Add<Core.Models.Theme>();
themeConfiguration.TemplateId(TemplateIDs.MaterialThemeTemplate);
themeConfiguration.SharedField(x => x.DarkerPrimaryColor).FieldId(FieldIDs.DarkerPrimaryColor);
themeConfiguration.SharedField(x => x.LighterPrimaryColor).FieldId(FieldIDs.LighterPrimaryColor);
themeConfiguration.SharedField(x => x.PrimaryColor).FieldId(FieldIDs.PrimaryColor);
themeConfiguration.SharedField(x => x.SecondaryColor).FieldId(FieldIDs.SecondaryColor);
```

And each individual color is mapped like this:

```
var colorConfiguration = loader.Add<Core.Models.Color>();
colorConfiguration.TemplateId(TemplateIDs.ColorTemplate);
colorConfiguration.Field(x => x.ColorHex).FieldId(FieldIDs.ColorHex);
colorConfiguration.Field(x => x.CssClass).FieldId(FieldIDs.CssClass);
colorConfiguration.Field(x => x.TextColor).FieldId(FieldIDs.TextColor);
```